# How to group subsequent rows with identical keys in a CSV file

Tags: python, string, csv

I am trying to concat col3 if col1 is equal to the same value in the line before and then write the output to a new file. I have a CSV file that looks like this:

```
col1,col2,col3
a,12,"hello "
a,13,"good day"
a,14,"nice weather"
b,1,"cat"
b,2,"dog and cat"
c,2,"animals are cute"
```

output i want:

```
col1,col3
a,"hello good day nice weather"
b,"cat dog and cat"
c,"animals are cute"
```

This is what i have tried:

```
import csv

with open('myfile.csv', 'rb') as inputfile, open('outputfile.csv','wb') as outputfile:
    reader=csv.reader(inputfile)
    writer=csv.writer(outputfile)
    next(reader)
    for row in reader:
        while row[0]==row[0]:
            concat_text=" ".join(row[2])
        print concat_text
        writer.writerow((row[0],concat_text))
```

It runs but i have no output. Help appreciated.

Comment: `while row[0]==row[0]: ...` will never advance, it is an infinite loop.

Answer (score 3):

If you're interested in using [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org/) you can group your `DataFrame` then output the unique values:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('test.txt')
print(df)
```

**Your original DataFrame**

```
  col1  col2              col3
0    a    12            hello 
1    a    13          good day
2    a    14      nice weather
3    b     1               cat
4    b     2       dog and cat
5    c     2  animals are cute
```

**The second DataFrame**

```
df2 = df.groupby(df['col1'])
df2 = df2['col3'].unique()
df2 = df2.reset_index()

print(df2)
```

Will result in:

```
  col1                              col3
0    a  [hello , good day, nice weather]
1    b                [cat, dog and cat]
2    c                [animals are cute]
```

To concatenate the third column, you'll need to use `apply` as such:

```
df2['col3'] = df2['col3'].apply(lambda x: ' '.join(s.strip() for s in x))

  col1                          col3
0    a   hello good day nice weather
1    b               cat dog and cat
2    c              animals are cute
```

---

**Complete code:**

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('test.txt')
df2 = df.groupby(df['col1'])

df2 = df2['col3'].unique()
df2 = df2.reset_index()

df2['col3'] = df2['col3'].apply(lambda x: ' '.join(s.strip() for s in x))

df2.to_csv('output.csv')
```

Comment: That's because `hello` had a space after it in original data.

Comment: @Leb remember to add `df2.to_csv('somefile.csv')`

Comment: @Ilja, indeed. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks, I think pandas is another great way to do this too

Comment: You're welcome. This answer is just meant as an alternative for you and any possible future viewers. The other answers here are spot on if you're unable to use `pandas`.

Answer (score 1):

```
import csv

with open('myfile.csv', 'rb') as inputfile, open('outputfile.csv', 'wb') as outputfile:
    reader=csv.reader(inputfile)
    writer=csv.writer(outputfile)
    prior_val = None
    text = []
    for line in reader:
        if line[0] == prior_val:
            text.append(line[2])
        else:
            if text:
                writer.writerow([prior_val, " ".join(text)])
            prior_val = line[0]
            text = [line[2]]
    if text:
        writer.writerow([prior_val, " ".join(text)])

>>> !cat outputfile.csv
col1,col3
a,hello  good day nice weather
b,cat dog and cat
c,animals are cute

>>> pd.read_csv('outputfile.csv', index_col=0)
                          col3
col1                              
a     hello  good day nice weather
b                  cat dog and cat
c                 animals are cute
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was you were comparing the same row with itself. This version compares the last row with the current row. The output is not quote delimited but it is correct. Contents of script.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import csv

with open('myfile.csv', 'rb') as inputfile, open('outputfile.csv','wb') as outputfile:
    reader=csv.reader(inputfile)
    writer=csv.writer(outputfile)
    next(reader)
    lastRow = None
    # assumes data is in order on first column
    for row in reader:
        if not lastRow:
            # start processing line with the first column and third column
            concat_text = row[2].strip()
            lastRow = row
            print concat_text
        else:
            if lastRow[0]==row[0]:
                # add to line
                concat_text = concat_text + ' ' + row[2].strip()
                print concat_text
            else:
                # end processing
                print concat_text
                writer.writerow((lastRow[0],concat_text))
                # start processing
                concat_text = row[2]
                print concat_text
            lastRow = row
    # write out last element
    print concat_text
    writer.writerow((lastRow[0],concat_text))
```

after running ./script.py the contents of outputfile.csv

```
a,hello good day nice weather
b,cat dog and cat
c,animals are cute
```